# CakePHP - MySQL query in Find method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hours.project_id
          , projects.name
          , sum(hours.spent_hours) AS expr1
          , sum(hours.invoiced_hours) AS expr2
              , hours.description
FROM
  projects
INNER JOIN hours
ON projects.id = hours.project_id
GROUP BY
  hours.project_id
, projects.id
, projects.name
, hours.description
```

How would you put pieces in FIND method in CakePHP? I tried several times but without any luck...

I have found this in documentation:

```
array(
'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
'recursive' => 1, //int
'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'), //array of field names
'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'), //string or array defining order
'group' => array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
'limit' => n, //int
'page' => n, //int
'offset'=>n, //int   
'callbacks' => true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
```

)

Other informations about databases:

Project hasMany Hours.
Hours belongs to Project.
In hours is project_id.

CakePHP 2.1.2.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are in the **Project Model** for the following lines.

```
$result = $this->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Hour.projetc_id', 
            'Project.id', 
            'Project.name', 
            'SUM(Hour.spent_hours) AS expr1', 
            'SUM(Hour.invoiced_hours) AS expr2', 
            'Hour.description'
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'Hour.projetc_id',
            'Project.id',
            'Project.name',
            'Hour.description'
        )
    )
);
```

You may also want to have a look [there](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/09/29/dealing-with-calculated-fields-in-cakephps-find/) to manage calculated fields in you array.

And lastly, I would recommend having a look at the [**Containable Behavior**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) as it will speed up your DB query and allow to really get only what you need from the DB.